# Spyder cannot launch: pyzmq

Tags: python, spyder, pyzmq

Upon launching spyder 3.3.6, I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('spyder==3.3.6', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 473, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2843, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2447, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2453, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 14, in <module>
    import zmq
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/utils/sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/backend/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/backend/select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'constants' from partially initialized module 'zmq.backend.cython' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/zmq/backend/cython/__init__.py)
```

Version of pyzmq is 20.0.0. Using pip, I've tried to update, uninstall-reinstall, and downgrade it to 19.0.2, but nothing helped. I'm using Debian testing, it's up to date.

Any ideas?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Spyder 3.3.6 is a year and a half old. Please update to our latest version, which is 4.2.0, either using Anaconda or a virtualenv and pip.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is the version that is included in the official Debian release. Do you suggest that I should go around the system, and install the newer version manually? Usually I try to avoid that to maintain system integrity.

Comment: Yeah, I think in this case is unavoidable because the version provided by Debian is way too old (as usual).

Comment: I see. Ok, I'll give it a try. Nonetheless, do you have an idea what this error message means?

Comment: No idea, sorry.